Zou He boundary condition for Lattice Boltzmann
I am utilizing this paper "https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.4593.pdf" to implement the Zou-He boundary condition, aiming to enforce a velocity of 1 at the inlet of the complex geometry. The modification involves adjusting the incoming distribution functions. However, upon completion, instead of attaining a density of 1 as expected, I obtain a value of 2 which leads to set the velocity to 0.5. This discrepancy aligns with the mathematical expressions involved. Consider an inlet vel_z=1: initially, the domain initializes with zero velocity across all components. Consequently, the distribution functions on the boundary lattices during the first iteration equal the weight functions, resulting in a summation of 1. After the modification of the incoming distribution functions, certain terms augment the existing distribution functions, logically causing an increase in their summation. This adjustment induces a significant reduction in the velocity of the lattices inside the domain adjacent to the boundary. I explored a lot of other resources including "https://pubs.aip.org/aip/pof/article-abstract/33/7/073304/1060984/Outflow-boundary-condition-of-multiphase?redirectedFrom=fulltext" but I face the same issue. by the way, I am able to apply the Zou He on D2Q9 model successfully. Can anyone help me to get what I am getting wrong in Zou He concept. I share some part of my code as a demo, It's not a programming issue but rather in conceptual question.
void Node::Initialize(std::shared_ptr<VelocitySet> velSet, int dir)
{
    double vel_z = 0.0;
    double rho = 1;
    double du = vel_z * velSet->GetDirection(dir)[2];
    double u_sqr = vel_z * vel_z;
    m_distributions.push_back(velSet->GetWeight(dir) * rho * (1 + 3 * du + 9 / 2 * du * du - 3 / 2 * u_sqr));
    m_newDistributions.push_back(0);
}


#ifdef D3Q19

void Boundary::Apply_ZouHe_Bc(std::shared_ptr<VelocitySet> velSet, Node& lat, std::vector<double>& vel)
{
    double rho = 1.0;
    double tmp = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < _nLatNodes; i++) {

        tmp += lat.m_distributions[i];
    }

    double Nx = (1.0 / 2) * (lat.m_distributions[0] + lat.m_distributions[6] + lat.m_distributions[7]
    - lat.m_distributions[1] - lat.m_distributions[10] - lat.m_distributions[11]) - (1.0 / 3) * (rho * vel[0]);

    double Ny = (1.0 / 2) * (lat.m_distributions[2] + lat.m_distributions[6] + lat.m_distributions[10]
    - lat.m_distributions[3] - lat.m_distributions[7] - lat.m_distributions[11]) - (1.0 / 3) * (rho * vel[1]);


    lat.m_distributions[4] = lat.m_distributions[5] + (1 / 3.0 * rho) * vel[2];

    lat.m_distributions[8] = lat.m_distributions[13] + (1 / 6.0 * rho) * (vel[2] + vel[0]) - Nx;

    lat.m_distributions[12] = lat.m_distributions[9] + (1 / 6.0 * rho) * (vel[2] - vel[0]) + Nx;

    lat.m_distributions[14] = lat.m_distributions[17] + (1 / 6.0 * rho) * (vel[2] + vel[1]) - Ny;

    lat.m_distributions[16] = lat.m_distributions[15] + (1 / 6.0 * rho) * (vel[2] - vel[1]) + Ny;

    tmp = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < _nLatNodes; i++) {

        tmp += lat.m_distributions[i];
    }
}

#endif

